# Skilled worker / specialized worker?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, translation

If a skilled worker is a "Worker, generally holder of a certificate of professional competence, who possesses a trade either through a long training period or through professional education", how can we convey the meaning of a worker whose job don't require any professional training or certificate (e.g. factory assembly line).

In French we say something that can be translated into "specialized worker", does it make sense in English?

Comment: Simple: an **unskilled** worker.

Comment: A *specialised* worker would be someone who has in-depth training and experience in a particular area, usually called a **specialist**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unskilled** worker sounds wrong to me, or rather ambiguous since **unskilled** might be interpreted as "someone who can't do his job properly".

If we look at https://www.lexico.com/definition/non-specialist we see that **non-specialist** when used as adjective conveys the meaning of "Not having or requiring specialist knowledge". So a non-specialist worker is someone not having/requiring specialist knowledge.

Although I still think it's better to describe the job as such rather than the worker.